# Jquery events does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'am trying to change the class of some input elements during some mouse events but only mouseover and mouseout events are working, what can be the reason of this problem ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.registerFormElements').mouseover(function(){
               this.className='bright';
       });
       $('.registerFormElements').mouseout(function(){
               this.className='';
       });
       $('.registerFormElements').focus(function(){
           this.className='bright';
       });
       $('.registerFormElements').blur(function(){
           this.className='';
       });
    });
```

Comment: its cool and working dude http://jsfiddle.net/AdqzA/1/

Comment: Your code works for focus and blur too: http://jsfiddle.net/6mHL3/ - but it doesn't make sense to remove the class on mouse out because the field could still have focus... In my opinion the particular handlers you're binding don't really work together to create a sensible user experience.

Comment: It is not working on my local host and i could not understand the reason of this.

Comment: @Deekey Actually, i have more than 1 input elements in my web page. Maybe that's the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could bind many events and look at the event.type and toggle the class you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.registerFormElements').on('focus mouseenter mouseleave blur', function(e) {
        var element = $(this);
        var shouldHaveBright = e.type === 'focus' || e.type === 'mouseenter';
        var hasFocus = element.is(':focus');

        element.toggleClass('bright', shouldHaveBright || hasFocus);
    });
});
```

Comment: this causes the same problem

Comment: @Tartar what kind of element is `.registerFormElements`?

Comment: they are all input text

Comment: is it because you have focus and then you do a mouse over and out? then you will have to check if the element has focus: http://jsfiddle.net/MMF64/

Comment: I get the idea but i have a question , why do i need to check if the element has focus ? we are already checking it by using the .focus() function, or aren't we ?

Comment: because how events work. it triggers when it happens you are doing like ´mouseenter => focus => mouseleave´ even tho you still have focus you have trigged an event that says if you are mouseleave then remove the class `bright`.

Comment: Thank you so much , i got it well.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the code :

```
$(this).attr('class', '');
```

or

```
$(this).attr('class', 'myClass');
```

and you can too

```
$(this).addClass('myClass');
$(this).removeClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
        var classname= 'bright';    
        /*Can create a variable so that you can use it later. By creating variable we can avoid searching in entire dom again*/
        var formElement = $(".registerFormElements");       
        /*Used chaining*/
        formElement.on( "mouseover focus", function() {                     
            $(this).addClass(classname);
        })
        .on( "mouseout blur", function() {                              
            $(this).removeClass(classname);
       });

});
```

Comment: Why would this work if the OP's code didn't work? (The OP's code [does work](http://jsfiddle.net/6mHL3/).)

Comment: @nnnnnn the jsfiddle example that you have given is not working for focus event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [**removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
 $(this).removeClass(); //It clears all classes
 $(this).addClass('MyClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Jqueries might be conflicting :-

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
   $j('.registerFormElements').mouseover(function(){
           this.className='bright';
   });
   $j('.registerFormElements').mouseout(function(){
           this.className='';
   });
   $j('.registerFormElements').focus(function(){
       this.className='bright';
   });
   $j('.registerFormElements').blur(function(){
       this.className='';
   });
});
```

Comment: OP said the mouse events were working, so there couldn't be a conflict.

Comment: Den i am deleting my answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working for me.  Check your class names don't have typos in them.  Also, by focus do you mean tab to the input?  This is what triggers focus events.

See my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AdqzA/

```
   $('.registerFormElements').mouseover(function(){
        this.className='bright';
   });
   $('.registerFormElements').mouseout(function(){
        this.className='';
   });
   $('.registerFormElements').focus(function(){
       this.className='bright';
   });
   $('.registerFormElements').blur(function(){
       this.className='';
   });
```

Comment: I have 5 input elements. I think that can be the reason of why your jsfiddle example is working. You have 1 input element in your example.

Comment: Why don't you try it with 5 then... okay here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/AdqzA/3/  And it's still working - you can tab between inputs and they are highlighted.